# Spring Data: findByEntityNot() in a many to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have the following many to many relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Foo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "foo_bar",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bar_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
  private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class Bar implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String name;

}
```

Now I want to query the FooRepository for all Foo's which DO NOT contain a Bar with the name "example". I tried to use the following Spring data method in FooRepository:

```
findByBars_NameNot(String barName);
```

But this returns one of every entry of the pivot table foo_bar which doesn't have "example" in its bar_name column. This means it can return duplicate Foo objects as well as Foo object which do actually contain a Bar with name "example" i.e. it's equivalent to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.foo_bar WHERE bar_name != "example";
```

Is there any nice way in Spring data to write a repository method to do what I am trying?

I have found the following native query which does what I need but I am hesitant to use a native query as I feel there is a cleaner way of doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.foo WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT foo_id FROM myschema.foo_bar WHERE bar_name = "example")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Spring Data JPA docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT b FROM f.bars b WHERE b.name = ?1)")
  Foo findByNotHavingBarName(String name);
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no support for `EXISTS` queries in the [query creation from method names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's a shame there isn't support for exists in the spring data method naming but this is certainly a lot tidier than what I was trying to do!